# Kafka not Publishing Oracle Data

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I have a Confluent on RHEL setup and am trying to read data from an Oracle 12C table/view (I tried both) and it is never creating messages at the consumer.

My suspicion is that that it has something to do with the data in the tables being loaded using a bulk loader and not unary inserts. I do have a unique incrementing id column in the data that I have specified, and the config loads and it shows my topic name as active/running.

Any ideas?

{

```
   "name":"oracle_source_05",
   "config": {
          "connector.class": 
          "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
          "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
          "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://<host>:8081",
          "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
          "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://<host>:8081",
          "connection.url": “<jdbc url>
          "connection.user" : "<user>",
          "connection.password" : "<pw>",
          "table.whitelist": "<view name>",
          "table.type" : "VIEW",
          "mode": "incrementing",
          "incrementing.column.name" : "<id column>",
          "validate.non.null":"false",
          "topic.prefix":"ORACLE-"
   }
```

}

Log has this message:

[2018-04-17 10:59:19,965] DEBUG [Controller id=0] Topics not in preferred replica Map() (kafka.controller.KafkaController)

[2018-04-17 10:59:19,965] TRACE [Controller id=0] Leader imbalance ratio for broker 0 is 0.0 (kafka.controller.KafkaController)

server.log:

[2018-04-18 09:24:26,495] INFO Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:39228 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)

[2018-04-18 09:24:26,498] INFO Client attempting to establish new session at /127.0.0.1:39228 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)

[2018-04-18 09:24:26,499] INFO Established session 0x162d403daed0004 with negotiated timeout 30000 for client /127.0.0.1:39228 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)

[2018-04-18 09:24:26,516] INFO Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x162d403daed0004 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)

[2018-04-18 09:24:26,517] INFO Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:39228 which had sessionid 0x162d403daed0004 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)

Comment: Are you using the odbc connector?

Comment: Please specify more detail. How are you trying to read data from Oracle? Are you using the Kafka Connect JDBC Source connector? If so what are you configuration files, how are you running Kafka Connect, are there any errors in the log files, etc?

Comment: I am using the Kafka Connect JDBC Source connector.

Comment: How are you running Kafka Connect? Are there any errors in the Connect log files?

Comment: I don't see any errors in the log...